# Getting UIButton object name into a string format

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have a lot of custom buttons in my program and I need to use methods to get their names. I've figured out how to get their names through their tag, but only a pointer to it. What I need is the name in a string.

Heres what I'm using:

```
-(void)pickRandomToHide {
    for (int check = 1; check <=5; check++)
    {
        int eventNumber = 1 + arc4random() % 43;
        UIButton *pick;
        pick = (UIButton *)[_mapImageView viewWithTag:eventNumber];
        [pick setAlpha: 0.5];
        NSString *buttonName;
        buttonName = [pick currentTitle];
        NSLog(@"%@",buttonName);
    }
}
```

The NSLog just gives 'Null' five times. But 5 buttons are disappearing so the start is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to be able to retrieve the variable name you assigned an object to.
That is not possible, as variable names get replaced with other symbols during compilation.

But also it is just not needed, as you can always track the pointer. If your code is depending on the variable names, you did something terrible wrong.

Comment: Ah okay thank you, I guess I'll have to just set a title to each button instead. I haven't done anything wrong, I just need the buttons to change picture on an event. The image is the button name + a colour at the end of it, so I was thinking that I'd just retrieve the object name and append the colour to it, and then use that with setBackGroundImage:

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean the "name" of a button? Do you mean the text on it? You can use UIButton's `textLabel` property, which will return a UILabel. You can then read that label's `text` property for the title of the button. In short:

```
NSString *buttonName = pick.titleLabel.text;
```

Comment: the label is called `titleLabel`and I think this code has the same effect as the currentTitle method

Comment: @Scott No, I'm looking to get the actual UIButton's object name. so if UIButton *button1; I want buttonName = @"button1"; from my example.